# Ember: transition to route passing the ID instead of obj

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have some route like /ads/:ad_id and from my controller I can do

```
this.transitionToRoute('ads.ad', adObj)
```

How can I do the similar thing but this time passing the ID instead of the loaded object?

O course I understand that I can load an obj by ID first, but Ember's power is in doing lost of boilerplate for us.

**Update**: So, as by default Ember serializes the model to URL params by doing like

```
mode_instance -> { model_name_id: model_instance.id }
```

My trivial attempt was doing

```
this.transitionToRoute('ads.ad', { id: adObjId })
```

But when passed a model object Ember does not re-fetch it.

So, the question: I have a route (single ad view) that depends on ad ID. I have this ID as number. I want to transition to this route like if I simply entered the url `/ads/ID`

Comment: Maybe I'm getting your problem wrong, but what is with `this.transitionToRoute('ads.ad', adObj.get('id'));`?

Comment: foc ourse I tried it. ember goes to `/ads/undefined`. Probably I can do what I need by overwriting the serialize hook

Comment: yeah, the `serialize` hook is an option I guess

Comment: actually not - see update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's your use case for this? Most cases when you would want to specify an object by id, you already have the object to pass to `transitionTo`. Can you provide more context about what you're trying to do? I think you can probably accomplish it without using the object id.

In any case, I don't think there's a good way to do this, because when you transition via `transitionTo(someRoute, someModel)`, the route's `model` hook is not called, and the model you pass in (`someModel`) is supplied directly to the other route hooks (`setupController(controller, model)`,  `redirect(model)`, `renderTemplate(controller, model)`).

See [Ember.JS Route api -- model method](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_model) for more details.

Comment: I do a save (HTTP POST). This save returns an object but due to some API specifics it doesn't have related data embedded. But this data is embedded when GET is done. So currently I have to do POST, then GET and then transitionTo

Comment: Just to clarify, are you using Ember-data?

Comment: Is there a problem with doing both the POST and the GET (after which you instantiate the object) and then passing the object to ```transitionTo```?

Comment: that's what I do exactly. but it's kind of repetitive job of what ember could handle itself when passed ID instead of object (and what it already does when going to URL)

Comment: That makes sense. What about just adding a class method to your model like ```MyModel.instantiateFromId(id)``` that wraps the POST and GET calls and returns an object? That way you just call ```transitionTo("route.action", MyModel.instantiateFromId(id))```. As my answer says, there's definitely no way of implicitly converting the id to objects for ```transitionTo``` right now.

Comment: yeah, I got you. I already did kind of this (actually I bit more generic helper: https://gist.github.com/emirotin/5614067)

Answer (score 8):

This can be accomplish by passing the URL to transitionTo.  For example,

```
this.transitionToRoute('/ads/' + adObjId)
```

The model() method will be called with the params from the URL.

Comment: Had to use this while trying to redirect to a url with a string-based, rather than an id-based dynamic segment.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a use case for this:

Transitioning from a list view to a detail view. In the list view, the records don't have any relations tied to them, but the detailed view should side-load relational data. For this reason, the models are not 1:1 between the list view and detailed view. There should be a way to transition simply using the id.

Cp